# Past Simple or Present Simple? Or both?

Tags: tense, past-simple, present-simple

[**Source**](http://english-4life.com.ua/uprajnenie/uprajpresent6.html)

Here is a sentence from a textbook. The task is to choose the correct tense, Past Simple or Present Simple:

> When your lessons (to be) over on Monday?

To me, both can be used here, as the context is very small. Is it right?

Comment: This clause (it is not, and cannot be, a sentence) seems to be taken from a Russian or Ukranian textbook which was obviously written by someone who neither speaks nor understands English. There is no sentence in English which can be written in this form, no matter what "tense" of the copula is used. It's a waste of your time.

Comment: Both "When your lessons were over on Monday?" and "When your lessons are over on Monday?" don't work in English, unless they're used as sort of echo questions. I agree with P. E. Dant.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Indeed, this clause is taken from a Russian textbook (in which it is given as a sentence).

Comment: @StoneyB The instructions are clear: "Expand the brackets." I think it's obvious that this question was written by someone in whose native language questions are ordered in the same way. Another on the same page is: _"It (to take) you long to find his house yesterday?"_ Note the same order here; and I'm half certain that the answer expected by the exam's creator is _"It **took** you long to find his house yesterday?"_

Comment: @P.E.Dant Oh, dear ... then I withdraw my comment. I keep hoping people who write tests will understand what they're testing.

Comment: @StoneyB To quote Rip Torn in _Payday:_ "Yeah, and people in hell want ice water."

Comment: You might actually write the sentence both ways. Those words as given are not sentences...

Answer (score 2):

Since **on Monday** can refer to next Monday, or to a Monday in the recent past, this past Monday, or even to Mondays in general (a native speaker might not say "on Monday**s**" but *on Monday* to refer to a day of the week in general terms when asking about a recurring schedule)  future, past, and present tenses are all valid here.  But the location of the verb must shift.

**When will your lessons be over on Monday?** (Monday next, or Mondays in general*)

**When were your lessons over on Monday?**  (probably the most recent Monday, this past Monday; a specific Monday in the distant past would be "that Monday" -- the police might ask "And where were you on that Monday?" to refer back to a particular Monday which is germane to their line of questioning)

**When are your lessons over on Monday?**  (Mondays in general*, or Monday next)

*some might consider this slightly below the standard "Mondays"